# Read layered hash from file

Tags: json, scala

In Scala, I would like to read a hash of hashes from a file.

A sample input is the content of this page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Sword

The only way I could think of reading this is to recursively split by `{`, `}` and `:`. This however seems a bit ugly.

Is there a way of reading this layered hash with relatively little code?

Comment: It is a "nested map" or "nested dictionary".  It's not a "hash" at all.  (Hash functions are often used to allow efficient lookup.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file is JSON.  It's a very well-known format.  There are multiple readers for Scala, including play-json, json4s, argonaut, circe, jawn, and others.

So as long as you can import a dependency (probably via SBT), yes, it will take very little code. *Which* code will depend on which of these you choose.

Jawn is fast, flexible, and minimal, so I usually choose it when I just want something basic.